# FT-818 - no xmit in CW

Tags: cw, yaesu, equipment-troubleshooting, qrp

I have a nearly brand new FT-818.  It works fine on digital modes, phone, etc.  however, when I plug in a straight key, and key the unit, it never breaks squelch.  I’ve checked the Breakin setting, and it’s correct.  The key works fine on my 857d.  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have VOX on?